# Is ReadyBoost supported on Windows Server 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012, readyboost

I've searched through forums and spec lists and don't see ReadyBoost in Windows Server 2012.  Can anyone confirm or know of a work-around?

Answer (score 7):

ReadyBoost is a feature of the consumer branch of Windows. It was not available on Server 2008 nor is it on Server 2012.

Comment: It's also effectively dead as that rationale for its existence has evaporated. The rationale was the 3.5GB RAM barrier not leaving enough room for both an adequate disk cache, OS structures, and applications. Hence, there was a benefit to moving some of the disk cache out of system RAM even if that meant it would be slower. Today, there is no such barrier and RAM is cheap and plentiful. So ReadyBoost has no application -- just buy more RAM instead. It's faster and more versatile.